# Remove Azure Storage Account Key

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-storage-account

I need to remove any Authentication Key that the Storage Accounts of my subscriptions. Do you know if there is any way to remove it? I was looking for a cmdlet in powershell to do it but was unable to find it.

I was able to retrieve the list of Storage Accounts and check if there is an authentication key set, however I was unable to remove them. I tried to set them as null, but it didn't work

```
$colStorageAccounts = Get-AzureRMStorageAccount
for ($objStorageAccount in $colStorageAccounts)
{
    $objAccountKey = Get-AzureRMStorageAccountKey -ResourceGroupName $objStorageAccount.ResourceGroupName -AccountName $objStorageAccount.Id
    if ($objAccountKey -ne $null)
    {
        here i should set the code for remove it
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think it's possible to remove, only to generate a new one

Comment: Thiago...you should put your comment as an answer please.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from the list of [commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.storage/?view=azurermps-6.13.0) supported on azure storage module, there is no command to delete account key, Instead you can remove the container if you need or generate a new one from the portal.

Comment: @GauravMantri no it does not, what i meant was to create new one